# Display horizontal rows vertically sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

when i issue select statement like

```
SELECT EMPID,ENAME,SALARY,DEPARTMENT from EMPLOYEE
```

then data shows like

```
EMPID     ENAME    SALARY   DEPARTMENT
---------------------------------------------
01        TEST1    2000     A/C
02        TEST2    3000     SALES
```

but now i want to show it like

```
EMPID       01      02

ENAME       TEST1   TEST2

SALARY      2000    3000

DEPARTMENT  A/C     SALES
```

so how to write sql for the above query.

Comment: How many rows do you expect to get on that table?, do you realize that when you have 200 employess, you will need 201 columns?, why would you need that?

Comment: Where are you displaying these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

First some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE tblTempValues
    (
        EMPID VARCHAR(100), 
        ENAME VARCHAR(100),
        SALARY INT, 
        DEPARTMENT VARCHAR(100)
    )

INSERT INTO tblTempValues
VALUES
    ('01','TEST1',2000,'A/C'),
    ('02','TEST2',3000,'SALES')
```

The get the columns to `PIVOT` on. I use the `ROW_NUMBER` over the `EMPID`:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tblTempValues.EMPID) AS RowNbr
    FROM
        tblTempValues
)
SELECT
    @cols=COALESCE(@cols +','+QUOTENAME(RowNbr),QUOTENAME(RowNbr))
FROM
    CTE
```

Then do a dynamic pivot like this. The `orderWeight` so that you will have the order of the columns:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N';WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT ''EMPID'' AS ID, CAST(EMPID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EMPID) AS RowId,1 as orderWeight FROM tblTempValues UNION ALL
    SELECT ''ENAME'' AS ID, CAST(ENAME AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EMPID) AS RowId,2 as orderWeight FROM tblTempValues UNION ALL
    SELECT ''SALARY'' AS ID, CAST(SALARY AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EMPID) AS RowId,3 as orderWeight FROM tblTempValues UNION ALL
    SELECT ''DEPARTMENT'' AS ID, CAST(DEPARTMENT AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EMPID) AS RowId,4 as orderWeight FROM tblTempValues
)
SELECT
    ID,'+@cols+'
FROM
    CTE
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Value)
    FOR RowId IN('+@cols+')

) AS p'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Then in my case I will drop the temp table

```
DROP TABLE tblTempValues
```

Answer (score 0):

First Off, The “Rows to columns” question comes up all the time, and I’d usually recommend a PIVOT() but in this case, you’re going to have a varying number of "columns" as and when you create new employees. So I don’t see how PIVOT() could be used. The only approach I could think of would be to resort to clunky iteration based SQL.

This answer goes against my better judgement, and will perform very badly if you have a large number of employees (I can’t stress this enough!) – But scheduled out of peak times, or for 1 off reports etc, it may suffice depending on your scenario.

```
--#### Create Dummy Data
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_ExampleData](
    [EMPID] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [ENAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SALARY] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [DEPARTMENT] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_ExampleData] ([EMPID], [ENAME], [SALARY], [DEPARTMENT]) VALUES (N'01', N'TEST1', CAST(2000 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'A/C')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_ExampleData] ([EMPID], [ENAME], [SALARY], [DEPARTMENT]) VALUES (N'02', N'TEST2', CAST(3000 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'SALES')
GO

--#### Select data as columns
DECLARE @CrossTabCursor CURSOR
DECLARE @CursorVal_EmpID VARCHAR(4)

-- #### Create the Basic Temp Table that we will build the crosstab data in
CREATE TABLE #tbl_CrossTabExample ( [-] VARCHAR(50) )

-- #### Populate the Y axis
INSERT  INTO #tbl_CrossTabExample
        ( [-]

        )
        SELECT  'EMPID'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'ENAME'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'SALARY'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'DEPARTMENT'


-- #### Add the nessasary columns - in this case, a varchar column per employee
SET 
@CrossTabCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT [EMPID] FROM [dbo].[tbl_ExampleData]
OPEN @CrossTabCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @CrossTabCursor
        INTO @CursorVal_EmpID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        -- #### Add column to the new table query based on the current cursor position (branch number)
        EXEC ('ALTER TABLE #tbl_CrossTabExample ADD [' + @CursorVal_EmpID + '] VARCHAR(50) NULL')

        -- #### Populate the new employee column
       EXEC ('UPDATE #tbl_CrossTabExample SET [' + @CursorVal_EmpID + '] = (SELECT EMPID FROM [tbl_ExampleData] B WHERE B.EMPID = ''' + @CursorVal_EmpID + ''') WHERE #tbl_CrossTabExample.[-] = ''EMPID''')
       EXEC ('UPDATE #tbl_CrossTabExample SET [' + @CursorVal_EmpID + '] = (SELECT ENAME FROM [tbl_ExampleData] B WHERE B.EMPID = ''' + @CursorVal_EmpID + ''') WHERE #tbl_CrossTabExample.[-] = ''ENAME''')
       EXEC ('UPDATE #tbl_CrossTabExample SET [' + @CursorVal_EmpID + '] = (SELECT SALARY FROM [tbl_ExampleData] B WHERE B.EMPID = ''' + @CursorVal_EmpID + ''') WHERE #tbl_CrossTabExample.[-] = ''SALARY''')
       EXEC ('UPDATE #tbl_CrossTabExample SET [' + @CursorVal_EmpID + '] = (SELECT DEPARTMENT FROM [tbl_ExampleData] B WHERE B.EMPID = ''' + @CursorVal_EmpID + ''') WHERE #tbl_CrossTabExample.[-] = ''DEPARTMENT''')

        -- #### move onto next branch
        FETCH NEXT FROM @CrossTabCursor 
                INTO @CursorVal_EmpID
    END 
CLOSE @CrossTabCursor 
DEALLOCATE @CrossTabCursor


-- #### Select the completed cross tab data
SELECT  *
FROM    #tbl_CrossTabExample

-- #### Drop the Temp Table
DROP TABLE #tbl_CrossTabExample
```

This answer is a VERY ROUGH proof of concept, for instance, you could use similar logic to dynamically build a PIVOT command wich would perform MUCH better.